# Get term by name using unsanitized name value

Tags: wordpress, themes

What i'm trying to do is to programatically set woocommerce product category.

What I have is the term name **`test & sample`** and the post id **`9`**, so to set the products category I have used **`get_term_by`** and **`wp_set_object_terms`**

```
$name  = 'test & sample';
$posid = 9;
//get the term based on name
$term = get_term_by('name', $name, 'product_cat');
//set woocommerce product category
wp_set_object_terms($posid, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
```

As you can see my problem is the unsanitized value of **`$name`**.
What I have done so far is replace **`&`** with **`&amp;`** which work.

```
$name = str_replace('&', '&amp;', 'test & sample');
$posid = 9;
//get the term based on name
$term = get_term_by('name', $name, 'product_cat');
//if term does exist,then use set object terms
if(false != $term){
  //set woocommerce product category
  wp_set_object_terms($posid, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
}
//if the term name doe not exist I will do nothing
```

My question is how to Get term by name using unsanitized name value or 
how to sanitize the name value to get the term id properly.

Answer (score 2):

You could try cleansing the `$name` with `$name = esc_html( $name );` before passing it to `get_term_by()`. I believe wordpress converts special HTML characters in terms, post titles, post contents, etc to their corresponding HTML entities so that the characters show up properly when the page is rendered.

Example:

```
$name = esc_html('test & sample'); // cleanses to 'test &amp; sample'
$posid = 9;
$term = get_term_by('name', $name, 'product_cat');
wp_set_object_terms($posid, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
```

Comment: It should escape any html characters from the term name, such as `<`, `>`, and `&`, which wordpress does to the tag names before saving them in the database so that they only have to be cleansed once rather than any time the term name is shown. This should help you find the correct term with only the name.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Plus one for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress sanitizes term names through `sanitize_term_field` (after a chain of functions, it does the real job). Looking the [code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1833) we can see that `name` passes through two filters:  `'edit_term_name'` and `'edit_category_name'` (lines 1880 and 1893). It seems that wordpress doen't plug any functions to those filters, so the only transformation occurs at line 1898; `$value = esc_attr($value);`

That said you can use `$name = esc_attr('test & sample');` and that should do the trick ;)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Plus one for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$name  = 'test & sample';
$postid = 9;
$term = get_term_by('name', apply_filters( 'pre_term_name', $name, 'product_cat'), 'product_cat');
if (is_object($term)) 
{
    wp_set_object_terms($postid, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
}
```

Comment: sanitize_title doesnt work since it will replace & with - and space with no space.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez that's exactly the point. `sanitize_title`will produce a `slug` you'd get for `test & sample` when you input into tag input field in wp-admin. `get_term_by` will then look for the term by `slug`. You can also omit `get_term_by` and just pass your unsanitized name to `wp_set_object_terms` as shown in the last line of code in my answer. It will create term if it doesn't exist or use existing one if it does. Have you even tried before saying it won't work?

Comment: Actually `get_term_by('slug'` doesn't need to be [sanitized](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) and its not what i need because I want to get the terms by name and not by slug.My problem is escaping the name.I hope you understand me.

Comment: I don't see where you got it from that it doesn't need to be sanitized. I have no idea why you're so hellbent on getting it by `name` instead of `slug`. Result is still the same - you'll still get false if taxonomy doesn't exist and `wp_term` object if it doe.

Comment: On line 857 in the link i have posted. you can see that the value is sanitized using your the same code sanitize_title() if 'slug'== $field. Why I wan to use name rather than slug is because thats the only information i have from outside wp. I only have name to check if a product should have a category or not. thats why ineed name and not slug. I am getting category name from api response so the best choide i think is to get the term by name if it does exist in woo.If category name does not exist in woo then there is no reason to create the category.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez You're right about auto sanitizing if it's `slug`, my bad. Though I still really fail to see, how it matters where you get it from. Whether you sanitize name you receive from API and search by name or pass unsanitized name and search by slug, result will still be the **same**.  There is no real difference, both ways work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104650/discussion-between-jameshwart-lopez-and-igor-yavych).

Comment: It seems like its not working if the slug is changed.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez updated yet again. tested and works even if slug was changed.

Comment: what version of wordpress you are using? seems like it doesnt even sanitized.and when i print_r $term, it doesnt have any output.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez 4.4.2 but that doesn't matter. Checked again, works just fine. do `var_dump` instead, probably `$term=false;`, i.e. the one you tried doesn't exist.

Comment: yes its returning false. and I check the category name exist.

Comment: Its actually getting the WP_Term object inside the themes file index.php but not in functions.php and also in the plugins file.

Comment: weird, you're sure that taxonomy (3rd param, `product_cat` in the example) is correct and you're supplying existing term? Because I checked again and it works fine. Take a look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/pO9VFgE.png) picture

Comment: Try to put that code inside functions.php or files inside any plugin it wont work. but inside index.php it works really great.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez Curious. And I have no idea why. Though if you turn it into hook, which will fire on` 'wp'` action for example, it'll work too. I think it should work at the point  where you get your API response.